# Access to user defined additions to the AspNetUser table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

ASP.NET and web programming is a bit new to me. I'm writing a web application in MVC5 that requires additional information besides what is available in the AspNetUser table.

I came across a good article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674760/Code-First-Migration-and-Extending-Identity-Accoun) for extending the table using code-first. I have added an `ExpirationDate` field to track when the user's subscription expires. The register, email validation and login work perfect without a hitch.

I next needed to allow the subscribed user to have access to their "dashboard". I tried using `[ChildActionOnly]` within the `AccountController` that pointed to a partial view set up in `_LoginPartial.cshtml`, but I was having problems with needing to call an async method to get the user data which gave me errors about blocking the thread. So I thought I would give everyone (currently subscribed or not) the Dashboard link on the menu and then handle it within the `DashboardController` redirecting them to the proper page. If they are not subscribed, then take them to the subscription page, otherwise take them to their dashboard. That means that the `DashboardController` will need an `ApplicationUserManager` and each of the functions will have to be async and do something similar to:

```
ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
if (user.ExpirationDate < DateTime.Today)
    return RedirectToAction("Expired");
else 
    theCorrectPage
```

I'm really not sure what is the best way to go about this.

1. Try to use the `AntiForgeryConfig.AdditionalDataProvider` (which I know little about and am not sure wouldn't conflict with OWIN)
2. Add the code above to each of the functions of a controller and just manually get the expiration date.
3. Use Roles and assign or de-assign the person a "Subscribed" role.
4. Venture into Claims (which seems to be the new way) and creating some kind of claim for subscribed members.

Is there a simple way of getting added user information on the fly without jumping through hoops? Is there a way to create an override so that `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` will take into consideration my new `ExpirationDate` field? I would have hoped that there was a way to override `UserManager` so i could create a `UserManager.GetExpirationDateAsync` method...

Just exactly what do you think the best way to go about this is?
Appreciate any and all enlightenment on this....
Thanks